# Flutter: How to detect platform-level edge swipes?

Tags: flutter, gesture, detection, platform

Is it possible to detect platform-level edge swipes in flutter? If so I'd appreciate how to do this. Either built in mechanisms or platform channel solutions are acceptable answers.

Specifically, on android systems, a platform-level edge swipe (left or right) will close the keyboard if it is active. Another edge swipe will exit the app. I don't need to control the function the platform swipe performs, only detect the platform swipe if the keyboard is open.

**Unrelated background on why this is needed:**
Manual keyboard control with screen redraws based on keyboard display have been created due to flutter's being terrible, however detecting a keyboard close from a system gesture is a problem. Using MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom is not an acceptable solution as this emits sequential inset values and constant complex UI redraws based on this are janky and slow. Also waiting for a 0 value on the insets is slow and non-responsive (around 500ms). To see the end functionality desired, system-swipe off a text box in whatsapp while typing in a chat. Detecting a 'lesser than current' value on mediaquery insets is also not a solution as showing/hiding emoji or functionality rows on the system keyboard emits changing 'lower' values while the keyboard is still supposed to be open.